# have to refresh to run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive thumbnail gallery for my portfolio website.
.gallerythumb is the thumb, and it's default width is 25%. My jquery, in theory, will resize the width of the thumbnail div containers based on the size of the page. It works, but the if/else statement only runs on page load, meaning I have to refresh the page, after I have resized the browser, to get it to run. Any clue what's going on?

```
    if ($(window).width() < 640) {
   $(".gallerythumb").css("width", "50%");
}
else if ($(window).width() < 260) {
   $(".gallerythumb").css("width", "100%");
  }
```

Comment: take a look on https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your gallery resize code in a function and then call that function on window resize as well as window load

```
function resizeGallery() {
   if ($(window).width() < 640) {
       $(".gallerythumb").css("width", "50%");
   }
   else if ($(window).width() < 260) {
       $(".gallerythumb").css("width", "100%");
   }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeGallery();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeGallery();
})
```